# Why Atom does not accept the syntax of JSX file?

Tags: jsx, atom-editor, syntax-highlighting

I have here this expression:

```
<QRCode
  value={`${formattedBchAddress}`}
  style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
/>
```

and Atom does not accept it, though it seems syntactically it is correct.

[image]

Comment: You'd have to report this as a bug in the relevant syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I‘m answering on the assumption that you did not install a package that provides JSX highlighting, but instead use the built-in `language-javascript`. Since JSX isn‘t part of the ECMAScript standard, I‘d argue that you shouldn‘t expect it to be supported by JavaScript language grammar.

Fortunately, there‘s the popular [language-babel](https://atom.io/packages/language-babel) which includes JSX support among other things. While this is the package with the most downloads and ratings, let me also point out that there are [alternatives](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=language+jsx&commit=Search) to choose from.

Comment: I did add `language-babel` to Atom, but still syntacs is incorrect. Shall I add maybe with `yarn add`?

Comment: Installing it is not enough, you need to assign the Babel grammar to your JSX files: https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/grammar/